# Extracting data from XML file to SQL Server in form of table

Tags: talend

I'm new to talend and have been trying to transfer the xml data (attached file) to SQL Server.

After using the `tFileinputXml`, `tmap_xml` and `tDBoutput` component only one row of the file was transferred.

Please guide me to populate multiple rows iteratively else guide me on converting the xml file to excel file.

Thanks in advance Smiley Happy

The tags in the files are columns while the string between tags is the data to be transferred as rows.

Comment: Please **show us** a sample XML, and the code you've used to import it. What works? Where are you stuck? What really is your question then??

Comment: The issues has been resolved at our end.The looping element was missing.Thanks for the reply.